# Complex number exercise with the power of 9

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given $z=-1+i$ and $w=\sqrt3+i$, find the smallest positive value of $n$ such that $\arg(z^n)=\arg(w^9)$. For this value of $n$, express the complex number $\frac{w^9}{z^n}$ in the form $x+iy$.

I found that $n=-\frac23$. I am not sure if this is correct. Please help me check this answer and show me how to solve the 2nd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}} $$

$$w=2e^{i\frac {\pi}{6}} $$

$$arg (w^9)=\frac {3\pi}{2} $$

thus

$$\frac {3n\pi}{4}=\frac {3\pi}{2} $$

and $$n=2.$$

$$z^2=2\sqrt{3}+2i $$

Comment: I understood :) thank you so much